# Copying and Pasting Filtered Table Problems

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

[image: Picture of the two pasted tables]

I have a sub that copies and pastes a filtered table to a new worksheet, however I want it to copy the cell values over only, NOT the formulas.

```
Sub PasteFilteredTableToTempSheet(ByRef TempWS As Worksheet, ByRef CalcWS As Worksheet)         
CalcWS.Activate
    
Dim NewTable As ListObject
Set NewTable = CalcWS.ListObjects("Full_Bearings_List")
    
NewTable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
Destination:=TempWS.Range("A1")

'TempWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

The 2 lines commented out do not do what I want, it copies the cell values but on the new worksheet the data is not formatted into a table, where as with the Destination syntax it automatically is formatted as a table but the formulas are also copied, not the values only.

The link shows the two examples. I want the format of the left image but with only table values, not the formulas.

Comment: Ok, so far I understand that you want to copy the data from a `Range` set as a `Table`.
But I'm puzzled. 
Do you want the `Destination` to be a `Table` as well ? 
If yes, do you want it to be formatted as the original `Table` from the source?

Comment: Yes, the table is orginally filtered and then I want to copy and paste the new 'filtered table' to a new worksheet, with the exact same format but only the cell values, not the formulas. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just paste twice.

```
TempWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
TempWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, try:

```
NewTable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
TempWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```